# OOP: Proper way to check other instances of objects' variables

Tags: c++, oop, composition

I have a collection of related classes, call them

```
class Manager {

    private:
       std::vector<Setting> m_settings;
}

class Setting {
    private:
        std::vector<Action> m_actions;
}

class Action {
    private:
        Keybind m_keybind;
}

class Keybind {
    public:
        UpdateKeybind;
    private:
        TYPE keybind;
}
```

As you can see from the pseudo-C++ code, Settings have actions, and actions have exactly one key binding. Now, as a user of my application you want to update the Keybind potentially, yes?

I currently have buttons in a keybind-type dialog associated with each action, so the action can handle updating it's own keybind.

**My Problem**:

How do I ensure that the Keybinding isn't bound to another object?

**Possible solutions**:

1. Move UpdateKeybind itself to the Manager class, then have Manager query all the settings.
2. Have a parent pointer in Action/Setting/Keybind so the Action can query the manager for updated keybind.
3. Have the Action query other Actions (not great conceptually as far as I can tell).

**What I need from you**:

1. What is the most rigorous approach, in terms of maintainability, speed, ease of understanding, and OOP appropriateness, to implementing checking if a Keybind is already found, whether out of my suggested solutions or something else entirely. I have already tried number 1 -- it works, but I feel like it could be better, ya dig?
   I was unable to find similar questions on StackOverflow, but if you do I'd love to see them!
2. Any other pro tips, things to improve are helpful.

Comment: are `Keybind` and `Action` strictly 1 to 1 or can an action be performed by many keys?

Comment: Good question. As implemented, it is a 1-1 relationship, and the user can modify the keybind through an interface (wxWidgets stuff)

Comment: Use std::map<keybinding, action> (or std::unordered_map). To see if key is bound to an action, check if a map contains the key (std::map::count), to change keybinding of an action, remove it from the map and add it with a new keybinding. The way you have it seems a bit backwards to me - your code maps action to key binding, but I bet that you want to look up an action for given key binding. Map should solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Amardeep says, you can try creating a class managing the mapping between actions and keybindings. Following is an example.  It will automatically remove the  keybind to the action if the there is new binding to that keybind.

```
class Manager {
    private:
       std::vector<Setting*> m_settings;
       KeybindPool *m_keybindPool;
};

class Setting {
    private:
        std::vector<Action*> m_actions;
};

class Action {
    public:
        void Bind(Keybind* keybind) {
            m_manager->m_keybindPool->Update(this, keybind)
        }
        Keybind* getKeybind() const {
            return m_manager->m_keybindPool->getKeybind(this);
        }
    private:
        Manager *m_manager;
};

class KeybindPool {
public:
    void Update(Action* action, Keybind* keybind) {
        if (m_keybindActionMap.find(keybind) != m_keybindActionMap.end()) {
            m_actionKeybindMap.erase(action);
        }
        m_keybindActionMap[keybind] = action;
        m_actionKeybindMap[action] = keybind;
    }
    Keybind* getKeybind(Action* action) {
        return m_actionKeybindMap[action];
    }
private:
    map<Keybind*, Action*> m_keybindActionMap;
    map<Action*, Keybind*> m_actionKeybindMap;
};

class Keybind {
    private:
        TYPE keybind;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an exactly 1:1 relationship between key bindings and actions, you could start with a pool of key binding objects and draw down from the pool as you configure actions.  So when offering up available keys for configuration, any keys already bound would not be in the available pool.